# excel hyperlinks containing data from another cell

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have a list of serial numbers in a column and I would like to create a hyperlink in a different column to a website that will contain the serial number found in the corresponding cell. For example:

[image]

Is there a way to input a formula using the hyperlink fx? Something like `=HYPERLINK(www.website.com/[A2]`?

Comment: Concatenate using `&`.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit? I am not familiar with that process.

Comment: `=HYPERLINK("www.website.com/" & A2)`?

Comment: Thanks, will this work if the serial number is in the middle of the hyperlink? For example, `=HYPERLINK("www.website.com/" & A2 & "/search")` ?

Comment: Sure, did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate with `&`:

```
=HYPERLINK("www.website.com/" & A2)
```

You can concatenate more text if needed:

```
=HYPERLINK("www.website.com/" & A2 & "/search")
```